# Create circular D3 Tree

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to create an interactive tree using D3. The final result shall have a circle which is supposed to expand the tree on click.

Currently the tree looks something like the following image. **The problem is, I want the root's children to be arranged around the root (something circular).** So that the children won't be aligned in  a row below the parent, but one is on the right side, one on the left and so on..

Is this even possbile with D3 Tree?
[image]

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";

import {select, hierarchy, tree, linkVertical} from "d3";

const data = {
    name: "M",
    children: [
        {name: "Test", children: []},
        {name: "Test-Tool", children: []},
        {name: "Test", children: []},
        {name: "Test CMS", children: []},
        {name: "Test Test", children: []},
        {name: "Test", children: []},
        {name: "Test", children: []},
        {name: "Test", children: []},
    ]
}

const InteractiveTree = () => {

    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = select(wrapperRef.current)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 600)
            .attr("height", 600)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
        const root = hierarchy(data);
        const treeLayout = tree().size([500, 300]);
        treeLayout(root);

        const linkGenerator = linkVertical()
            .x(node => node.x)
            .y(node => node.y);

        svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(root.descendants())
            .join("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .attr("cx", node => node.x)
            .attr("cy", node => node.y);

        svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(root.links())
            .join("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("d", linkGenerator)
    }, [])


    return (
        <div ref={wrapperRef}>
        </div>
    )
};

export default InteractiveTree;
```

Comment: You're looking for a `radialTree`, and yes, it's possible! You can search observablehq.com or bl.ocks.org for examples